# Trying to download photos from iPhone 5s to Windows 10

Tags: iphone, windows, photos

I just got a new computer with Windows 10. I have saved my pictures from my iPhone 5s to the computer however there is a block of photos from May 1-24 that it will not detect and therefore will not download.  It will not even allow me to see these photos on the computer, so I can't manually select them for download.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should download "OneDrive" on your iPhone. Then on your OneDrive account you set your iPhone to upload all pictures on Photos. All your pictures will be uploaded. Then you open https://onedrive.live.com by your Windows 10. It can work with iCloud as well, but I like OneDrive more. That's how I duplicate my pictures on iPhone to Windows 10. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can sync all your photos to iCloud and then search icloud.com on your Windows to download. Or you can try a 3rd-party app, AirMore, to [transfer photos from iPhone to Windows 10](http://airmore.com/iphone-photos-to-windows-10.html).

1. Install it on your iPhone and scan QR code on [AirMore Web](http://airmore.com/web.html) on your PC.
2. Tap "Pictures" on your computer to find photos you need, and click "Download".

Hope both ways could help you get the photos.